# How to use dplyr mutate to perform operation on a column when a lag variable and another column is involved

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

Suppose I have a data frame like this

```
> dat
  a          b         c
1 1  0.3321008 0.3321008
2 2 -0.2946729        NA
3 3 -0.1447266        NA
4 4 -0.9415429        NA
5 5 -1.0165080        NA
```

here is the `dput`

```
structure(list(a = 1:5, b = c(0.332100835317822, -0.294672931641969, 
-0.144726592564241, -0.941542877670977, -1.0165079846083), c = c(0.332100835317822, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to perform an operation on the `c` column such that `c = lag(c)*b` (except for the first element in c

I can do this using a simple for loop as below

```
for(i in (1:4)){
  dat$c[i+1] <- dat$c[i]*dat$b[i+1]
}
```

Output:

```
> dat
  a          b           c
1 1  0.3321008  0.33210084
2 2 -0.2946729 -0.09786113
3 3 -0.1447266  0.01416311
4 4 -0.9415429 -0.01333517
5 5 -1.0165080  0.01355531
```

How do I do this using dplyr mutate ? or using apply functions?

Comment: Whether in dplyr or not, you seem to need `dat$c[1]*cumprod(replace(dat$b, 1, 1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing the math, we can avoid the iterative computation:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(c = cumprod(replace(b, 1, 1))*c[1])
```

Comment: Thankyou Frank! Okay, in this case the math made it easier, what if I have a polynomial function with two variables one of which is the lag and other is from the other column. Function example: `5*b + exp(lag(c))`

Comment: @Kou In that case, if performance doesn't matter, I guess I'd use a loop; and if it does, a loop in Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks Frank! I was hoping there might be some way we could do that in the pipe without the loop!